# Can an MDB listen to multiple listener ports

Tags: jms, websphere, message

Can I set up one MDB to listen to more than one listener port? Each listener port will be connected to one particular queue.
If not, why is the restriction that one MDB can listen to only one port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. An MDB may only be associated with one listener port (or one activation specification).

As a possible workaround to this limitation, you can configure your MDB multiple times so that each one can be bound to a different queue (listener port / activation spec).

Answer (score 0):

MDBs are deployed to an application server.  The application server is typically only listening on one port.  You can build a simple java application that creates different connections to different servers; in a configurable way though.  Just not as MDBs.

Comment: I think you may be referring to an http port, but OP is concerned with [listener ports](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0503_bhasin/0503_bhasin.html), which is a service hosted on a WAS application server used for connecting message-driven beans to message queues.

Answer (score 0):

MDB's are a layer(probably several) of abstraction(s) above the concept of a port. Most messaging implementations will broker traffic across a single port,but likely a combination of data/control ports.

Think of the broker like a mail depot the letters come in and the broker puts them in the right mailbox while providing a number of other services(peer failover/communication, persistence, guaranteed delivery, message acknowledgment, etc.).

MDBs are the agents that subscribe to those abstract mailboxes. They really have no understanding of the underlying architecture. As far as they are concerned things are all happening locally in memory. Their only job is to adhere to the EJB standard and the container (typically through the application of more low level standards like JCA layered again over raw sockets) takes care of making sure the messages arrive at their destinations.

Maybe it would be helpful if you further elaborated on why you are concerned about how your MDBs relate to ports

Comment: I think OP is referring to WebSphere [listener ports](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0503_bhasin/0503_bhasin.html), which is a component that the MDB is bound to in WAS in order to listen to message destinations; I don't think OP is concerned with the underlying networking ports used by MDBs.